# Gson to parse JSON file where root element is not constant

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a json file which looks like this -

```
 {
  "gmps-camino": [
    {
      "id": "2903315183",
      "category": "NEW",
      "year": "2016",
      "make": "Chevrolet",
      "model": "4500 Gas",
      "trim": "2WD Reg Cab 150&quot;",
      "type": "",
      "price": "56001.000000",
      "photo": "http://inventory-dmg.assets-cdk.com/chrome_jpgs/2016/24174x90.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "2774517143",
      "category": "NEW",
      "year": "2016",
      "make": "Chevrolet",
      "model": "Cruze",
      "trim": "Sedan L",
      "type": "CAR",
      "price": "17495.000000",
      "photo": "http://inventory-dmg.assets-cdk.com/RTT/Chevrolet/2016/3077853/default/ext_GAZ_deg01x90.jpg"
    }
  ]
 }
```

I am trying to use Gson to parse it and created a class to mimic it -

```
public class VehicleJson {
  String builder
  List<VehicleWithoutBuilder> vehiclesWithoutBuilder;
}

class vehicleWithoutBuilder {
  String id;
  String Category;
  String year;
  String make;
  String model;
  String trim;
  String type;
  Double price;
  String photo;
}
```

I want the value of root element that is "gmps-camino" to be inserted in builder and the rest of JSON in vehiclesWithoutBuilder list. So far my attempts to parse this file are in vain as Gson thinks there is no class called gmps-camino and gives me null for both string and the list. What would be the right way to do it ?

here's the code that I am trying to parse this -

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jsonFileName));
Gson gson = new Gson();
VehicleJson vj = gson.fromJson(br, VehicleJson.class);
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you are parsing json ?

Comment: Do you want to put the Json array named "gmps-camino" in the String "builder" as string and  need to set the parsed value to the vehiclesWithoutBuilder List ?

Comment: @DerickDaniel Added code that I was using to parse the json.

Comment: @Rohitchauhan Check my answer hope it helps

Comment: @J.R Yes, the "gmps-camino" needs to go in the variable called "builder". However the problem is that it won't always be "gmps-camino", it could be anything. Its basically the name of the builder of the vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Your Bean should be structured differently, It should be like this:

```
public class VehicleJson {
  Map<String,List<VehicleWithoutWebID>> vehicles;
}

// Now lets parse the JSON and construct the BEAN
VechicleJson vehicleJson = new Gson().fromJson("yourInput.json",VehicleJson.class);
```

Comment: This makes logical sense, but gson keeps returning null for me.

Comment: I have tested it in my dev environment and it's working fine.

Comment: Did you use the same Json and class that I have pasted here ?

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, if required you can use `JSONParser` and `JSONArray` to your code. Try the following piece of code and modify the name according to your need:

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

   try {   

          Object objct = parser.parse(new FileReader("...")); //the location/name of your json file
          JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) objct;
          JSONArray objs = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("gmps-camino");
          for (Object obj : objs) {
               JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) obj;
               String gmps = (String) jobj.get("gmps-camino");
               System.out.println(gmps);
          }
      }
```

You need to change the names accordingly.

For reference, see "Example" on the [json-simple decoding example](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/wikis/DecodingExamples.wiki) page.

Alternatively, you can check the following GSON usage:

```
private static final Type VEHICLE = new TypeToken<List<vehicleWithoutBuilder>>() {
}.getType();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
    List<vehicleWithoutBuilder> data = gson.fromJson(reader, VEHICLE ); // contains the whole list
    data.toScreen(); // prints to screen some values
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the structure of your class try this

Change your  VehicleJson  as

```
public class VehicleJson {
  String builder;
  @SerializedName("myKey")
  List<VehicleWithoutBuilder> vehiclesWithoutBuilder;
}
```

And change the dynamic root key value to "myKey"

```
public JsonObject modifyJson(String inputJson) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(inputJson).getAsJsonObject();

        //Get the random key
        String key = jsonObject.keySet().iterator().next();

        //Take a copy of the Array
        JsonElement copyArray = jsonObject.get(key);

        //Remove from JsonObject
        jsonObject.remove(key);

        String customKey = "myKey";

        jsonObject.add(customKey , copyArray);

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

And parse with GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

        JsonObject jsonObject = modifyJson(json);

        VehicleJson result = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, VehicleJson.class);
```

And manually map the String value of Json array to builder variable

```
result.builder = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("myKey").toString();
```

Comment: Why are you making this so complicated ?

Comment: Its just changing the value of the random key. Its useful if he don't want to change the Class structure.